# Are gemstones a limited resource in Future Redeemed?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3, xenoblade-3-future-redeemed

Are there a limited number of gemstones you can collect in *Xenoblade Chronicles 3: Future Redeemed*?

I know gemstones can be found in single-use containers, but I don't know if there's an alternative source that respawns. Gemstones are needed in order to craft gems. I've also noticed also noticed that I can save on gemstones by [skipping gem levels](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/wg0t2r/psa_you_can_skip_gem_levels/). If gems are a limited resource, I'd like to my upgrades more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main game, there's always a chance of getting more gemstones from re-killing unique monsters. I believe this is also the case in FR, but it matters less because there aren't enough gems to make to run out of gemstones for them (at least in my experience).